# MVVM Light variables and Messaging

Tags: wpf, scope, mvvm-light, messaging

I have a question about MVVM Light in WPF 4.5.  It shouldn't require any code.  I am just curious what happens when I send a message to trigger a viewmodel to send BACK to the original viewmodel an ICollectionView.  Are they now two separate copies, or am I accessing the original that I requested?  If I am not, how do you access the original variable so that you don't have 'new' up a second ICollectionView ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand your problem:

You have two ViewModel call VM1 and VM2.

VM1 could listen the messages from VM2 like that:

```
  Messenger.Default.Register<ICollectionView>(this, HandleCollectionReceived);   
  private void HandleCollectionReceived(ICollectionView collection)
  {
    // do stuff with the collection
  }
```

Then VM2 can send the original collection to VM1 like that:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(MyCollectionView);
```

Or a copy like that:

```
var MyCopy = new CollectionView(MyCollectionView);
Messenger.Default.Send(MyCopy);
```

In other words: you choose what you send in the message, thus you choose if you send an original or a copy of your object.

Comment: Okay so I do send the collection that is already declared in vm2 to vm1.  I set a variable in vm1 to the value of the collection, because the variables original name is not what I want for a name.